# How to trigger custom function on lifecycle events?

Tags: pulumi

How do I instruct Pulumi to invoke my custom Typescript function when `pulumi up` or `pulumi destroy` is invoked from command-line?

I tried invoking my function from the main code block, but it is getting invoked multiple times on `pulumi up`.

Further, there are some commands I only want to invoke for `up` and others that should only be invoked for `destroy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pulumi.runtime.isDryRun()` to run code or functions only during `update`. Pulumi doesn't currently expose a way to hook into lifecycle events, but this is on the roadmap at https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi/issues/1691.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with this function to be called async you can wrap your stack using [Pulumi Automation API](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/guides/automation-api/) and provide [`onEvent`](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/nodejs/pulumi/pulumi/automation/#UpOptions-onEvent) option when [invoking it using TypeScript](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/guides/automation-api/getting-started-automation-api/#invoke-pulumi-commands-against-the-stack):

```js
stack.up({
  onEvent: (event) => {
    if (event["preludeEvent"] !== undefined) {
      // run something once before changing resources
      return
    }
  },
})
```

The same can be done during [destory](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/nodejs/pulumi/pulumi/automation/#DestroyOptions-onEvent)

---

- [github.com](https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi/blob/01f52892191cfbaf9fcc233746e473bfa1129927/sdk/nodejs/automation/events.ts#L178-L200) - more details on what types of events are available.
- [dev.to](https://dev.to/fllstck/observable-infrastructure-as-code-52ha) - detailed blog about using pulumi automation events